# Parsing Email in proper format from Web Speech API Transcript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using web speech API in chrome to get a string (transcripts) I want it to be able to parse emails as `example@gmail.com` not `example at the rate gmail.com` can we transform it to expected output using Regex or any kind of alternative?

Current output from voice (not useful)

```
David at the rate gmail.com
David at Gmail.com
Stacy at the rate gmail.com
Stacy at Gmail.com
```

Expected output to be (will be useful)

```
David@gmail.com
Stacy@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

First split the string into an array of lines and then only select the lines with "at the rate"

```
let lines = emailstring.split('\n');
for( i = 0; i < lines.length ; i += 2 ) lines[i] =  lines[i].replace(" at the rate ", "@");
console.log(lines);
```

The splitting of the string into lines can also be done with regex.

Comment: at or at the rate both are to be @